# Deleting selected checkboxes using java swing

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am new to java swing. I have a code that generates checkboxes. I want to have a button somewhere in my frame, which on clicking, should delete the selected checkbox entries. Here is what I have so far.

```
public class Scroll extends JPanel  {  


public static void main(String[] args) {   
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){  
         public void run()    {  
             createAndShowGUI();   
             }   
         });   
     }   
 public static void createAndShowGUI()     {  
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame with ScrollBar"); 
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
     JComponent newContentPane = new ResultButtonBar();
     newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
     JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(newContentPane); 
     scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);  
     frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);  
     frame.setSize(800, 800); 
     frame.setVisible(true);
     JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
     frame.add(startButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "basdsadad");

                }
        });

    }

  }
```

and the new ResultButtonBar().java

```
public class ResultButtonBar extends JPanel  {   

  private HashMap<JCheckBox, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    private JLabel _label;

    private static final int MAX_CHECKS = 1000;

    public ResultButtonBar() {
        super();

        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setVisible(true);

        JCheckBox checkBox;
        Random r = new Random();

        JPanel checkPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        _label = new JLabel("You selected nothing");
        checkPanel.add(_label);

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHECKS; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                Integer temp = (r.nextInt()) % 100;
                a.add(temp);
                sb.append(temp).append(" ");
            }

            checkBox = new JCheckBox(sb.toString().trim());
            checkBox.setName("CheckBox" + i);

            map.put(checkBox, a);
            checkPanel.add(checkBox);
        }

        add(checkPanel);

    }

}
```

Comment: In the checkPanel use getComponents(). For each check whether it's an instance of the JCheckbox and if it's selected remove it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, keep all your check boxes in an `ArrayList` so you will have a reference to them when you need it.

Then, add a `JButton` wherever you need. Then iterate over this `ArrayList` and call `invalidate()` on the component which contains your check boxes. Next statement would be to call the `remove()` method on the container; the `checkPanel`.

Alternatively, you may call `removeAll()` if all the components in the container are check boxes and you want to remove them.

*The alternative pointed by StanislavL is also a good one if you have a lot of different components along with check boxes*

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two approaches:

- if You are maintaining one  `JPanel` instance  which contains only the instances of `JCheckBox`, then you can first get all the checkbox's using `panel.getComponents()` method, check their selection state and depending on the state remove it by calling `panel.remove(component)`. For example:

  ```
  Component checkBox[] =  checkBoxPanel.getComponents();
   for(Component c:checkBox)
     if(((JCheckBox)c).isSelected())
       checkBoxPanel.remove(c);
   checkBoxPanel.revalidate();
   checkBoxPanel.repaint();
  ```

  The last call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the `checkBoxPanel` is important for reflecting changes on the layout and graphics rendering of the components.
- You can use `ItemListener` with the instances of `JCheckBox` to do things on selection state change. Use an instance of `ArrayList<JCheckBox>` to add the `selected checkBox` to the list. However you should use an implemented ItemListener: `MyItemListener implements ItemListener` and create one instance and add this instances to all the `checkboxes` to react on state change. You can use event source `e.getSource()` to get the `JCheckBox` instance on which the `ItemEvent` is performed.

**Tutorial resource:**

1. [How to Write an Item Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html)

Comment: I updated my actionListener method as follows                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
    Component checkBox[] =  checkPane.getComponents();
     for(Component c:checkBox){
       if(((JCheckBox)c).isSelected()){
         checkPane.remove(c);
     checkPane.validate();
//    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "basdsadad");
       }
     }
   }
   });                                    But it is returning NullPointerException.

Comment: @user2945142, the code you written is not well understood but check that your `checkPane` is initialized. I think you are mistakenly using `checkPane` instead of `checkPanel` or you haven't added any checkBox to `chekPanel` at all. Please check them out